Who can use the automated emigration gates at BKK airport?
As I exited Thailand last month via BKK airport after some conference in Bangkok, I attempted to use the eGates at BKK instead of going through immigration officers. That didn't work and I was told to through an immigration officer. This made me wonder: who can use the automated emigration gates at BKK airport? E.g., does that depend on the nationality or the flight? Assume that the passenger is in good standing, e.g. didn't overstay.

Not sure about BKK but I went through CDG a few times this year and the availability of e-gates seemed to be completely random. I had about 50/50 hit rate.

At what point did it fail? After scanning the passport, or after whatever biometrics scan they use? Do you usually get through in other eGates?

@jcaron After scanning the passport. I didn't have any issue going through eGates in Singapore last year.

@FranckDernoncourt: that might have been just a case of the scanner not being able to read your passport. I've certainly had a few of those one's too

I don’t think there is any reason for it to depend on the flight. I see three possible reasons: incompatibility between the biometrics stored in the passport (fingerprints or face) and the sensors in the eGate; a limitation on what nationalities are allowed to use the eGates (they may want/have to check stamps in the passport), or simply that it didn’t match (sometimes the data recorded in the passport is bad quality, sometimes it’s the data recorded by the eGate, especially in the case of fingerprints).

If it was after the passport scan then it’s either if the first two. There’s also the possibility the MRZ was not correctly scanned, I’ve had a (French) passport with a slightly smudged MRZ which regularly triggered issues for example. But you would probably have noticed that if it was your case.

https://chiangsaen.immigration.go.th/en/passengers-all-nationalities-holding-e-passport-are-now-eligible-to-use-the-immigration-auto-channel-to-leave-thailand-at-the-international-departure-passport-control-suvarnabhumi-airport/ says all nationalities are allowed. (on exit). Which results in a conundrum, I believe all French passports for a very long while have both fingerprints and biometrics. Could just be a dirty passport scabbing plate…

@jcaron fingerprints on passport cannot be accessed without "active authentication", which requires thailand to be issued a digital certificate by the country that issued the passport to do "active authentication". I strongly doubt they even think about fingerprints, considering they allow all nationalities. Biometric face picture can be accessed in any case. You did not mention your passport, but most countries store face pictures as JPEG, some as JPEG2000 (an incompatible, better format), as allowed by standard. Maybe Thailand can only handle JPEG and not JPEG2000? Could be anything, really.

@jcaron I believe you're right. Could you please post your comment as an answer? Thanks
